# Multiple Values for a single key in a dictionary

Tags: python, html, dictionary, key

I am currently writing a script that extracts data from an xml and writes it into an html file for easy viewing on a webpage.

Each piece of data has 2 pieces of "sub data": Owner and Type.

In order for the html to work properly I need the "owner" string and the "type" string to be written in the correct place. If it was just a single piece of data then I would use dictionaries and just use the data name as the key and then write the value to html, however there are 2 pieces of data.

My question is, can a dictionary have 2 values (in my case owner and type) assigned to a single key?

Comment: The value could be e.g. a two-tuple `(owner, type)` or a sub-dictionary `{'owner': owner, 'type': type}`.

Comment: So in essence a list within a dictionary, and then take the 2nd list value for type and the 1st for owner?

Comment: A list would also be acceptable, although a tuple is more traditional. Any object can be a dictionary value - the only limitation is that keys must be hashable (having said that, a tuple of strings would be an acceptable key, too!)

Comment: @jonrsharpe a tuple of strings is exactly what I need, because "owner" will be an email address and "type" will end up being "USAGE" or "KPI" or some indication of what type of data is contained in that file.

Comment: Then it's up to you whether you prefer to access that data by e.g. index in a tuple (`value[0]`) or key in a dictionary (`value['owner']`). There is also a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) that you could use to access the data by attribute (`value.owner`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object can be a value in a dictionary, so you can use any collection to hold more than one value against the same key. To expand my comments into some code samples, in order of increasing complexity (and, in my opinion, readability):

**Tuple**

The simplest option is a two-tuple of strings, which you can access by index:

```
>>> d1 = {'key': ('owner', 'type')}
>>> d1['key'][0]
'owner'
>>> d1['key'][1]
'type'
```

**Dictionary**

Next up is a sub-dictionary, which allows you to access the values by key name:

```
>>> d2 = {'key': {'owner': 'owner', 'type': 'type'}}
>>> d2['key']['owner']
'owner'
>>> d2['key']['type']
'type'
```

**Named tuple**

Finally the `collections` module provides [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which requires a little setup but then allows you to access the values by attribute name:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', ('owner', 'type'))
>>> d3 = {'key': MyTuple('owner', 'type')}
>>> d3['key'].owner
'owner'
>>> d3['key'].type
'type'
```

Using named keys/attributes makes your subsequent access to the values clearer (`d3['key'].owner` and `d2['key']['owner']` are less ambiguous than `d1['key'][0]`).

Answer (score 0):

As long as keys are hash-able you can have keys of any format. Note, tuples are hash-able so that would be a possible solution to your problem

Make a tuple of case-owner and type and use it as a key to your dictionary.

Note, generally all objects that are hashable should also be immutable, but not vice-versa. So